# flask app write to file on exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

What is the simplest way to reliably save data to a file when flask app.run() stops/crashes?

```
try:
   app.run()
except Exception as e:
   #<cleanup and save>
```

Does not work for sigint/ctrl+c etc they must be try/excepted in app.run()

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
app.run()
signal.pause()
```

works for ctrl+c (but not always)

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def save_on_exit(error):
    # <cleanup and save>
    return response
```

works on error in views.

Is there a solution that just writes to the file on exit, or do I need all 3 of those?

Comment: See `atexit` or `signal` standard libraries.

Comment: Short answer: there's no __reliable__ way to do anything "when an app crashes" - for example you cannot expect to allocate any memory after a MemoryError or to write to disk if your filesystem is dead or full (and those are only two examples).

Comment: I tried signal it caches ctrl+c but not reliably, atexit does not catch ctrl+c but it works for the rest.

Comment: This is related to flask app.run()